# FormCollection not getting correct value for Radio Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

When I post the FormCollection and try to get the value of my radio button, it always takes the value of the last Radio Button (no matter which one is checked). Why is it doing this? My temporary workaround is to create a hidden value and add an onclick JS method. I've tried using pure HTML code with the same result.

**Code for View**

```
@Html.RadioButton("Radio", "No", true, new { id = "Radio0"}) + " No");
@Html.RadioButton("Radio", "Yes", false, new { id = "Radio1"}) + " Yes");
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<input checked="checked" id="Radio0" name="Radio" type="radio" value="No"> No
<input id="Radio1" name="Radio" type="radio" value="Yes"> Yes
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult MyPostBack(FormCollection form)
{
    string radio = form["Radio"]; //************** this is always "Yes"
    return View("MyView");
}
```

Comment: The Post back is by a 3rd party control. I could try using a ViewModel anyway though. Could you post a link to an example though? I think I know what you mean, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's DevExpress and I can control the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually could not replicate the issue. It correctly identifies the selected radio button on PostBack at the controller.

You may want to check the code for your view (with your given syntax for the View, it shouldn't render the page in the first place & should be throwing a compilation error)

This was the view I was testing against

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyView";
}

<h2>MyPostBack</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButton("Radio", "No", true, new { id = "Radio0"}) @:No
    @Html.RadioButton("Radio", "Yes", false, new { id = "Radio1"}) @:Yes
    <input type ="submit" runat="server" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, since you are using `DevExpress`, first go through the provided documentation. It should point you in the right direction. Doing some Google search,found out that in addition to the `RadioButton` extension there is also a `RadioButtonList` extension. Here are few links that could help you.

[DevExpress documentation (RadiButtonList)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9026)

[A working example on using RadioButtonList](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2871.aspx)

[A discussion thread on RadioButton](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q382536.aspx) (though I couldn't find an example on how to use `RadioButton`; according to the thread you can use `RadioButton`, if is has the option to choose between two choices; else you need to opt for `RadioButtonList`)

Also as everyone mentioned it is bettor to pass a `Model/ViewModel` rather than sending over the `FormCollection`

Comment: I was using ViewContext.Writer.Write because the form is within a third party control that I didn't want to even get into. I'm also not using a submit button, it's a post back created by the control. Perhaps it's a bug with the control I'm using. I'll make a simple example page and then post an update.

Comment: So you are using DexExpress MVC Extensions. I don't think there is a bug (else there will be plenty of discussion in forums around this). I have edited my post; have a look.